# Сайты с туториалами по GWT, SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, java

Существуют ли сайты с туториалами типа  [java2s.com](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/CatalogGWT.htm),
но примеры такие как регистрация/вход, работа с базой datasource и так далее
интересует GWT, а именно SmartGWT. Так как там уже есть хорошие таблицы  и слайдер по крайней мере

Comment: А официальная дока не подойдет?

Comment: смарт доки не рекомендуют использовать стандартные виджеты gwt, а вот по доках смарта, мало что понятно, видео уроки само круто, но о таком только мечтать. не знаю как mvp с презентарами, историей, переход на различные внутренние gwt страницы реализовать. везде в примерах одна страница, и большинство примеров без mvp сделаны. идеальный пример таблица с вычисляемой логикой, которая делается в модели, евенты обрабатываются в контроллере, и есть полноценный вход\регистрация, больше чем одна страница. Поможет кто нибудь?

Comment: http://www.experika.com/ui/#!intro/first
вот кто не знал сайт на gwt, чистом, все элементы свои, а мне всего то надо...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main](http://)
Это много виджетов

[http://www.smartclient.com/](http://)
Отсюда много ссылок на разные примеры

[http://uptick.com.au/blog?page=5](http://)
Начало отличного примера (только смотреть (листать) его надо с конца к началу)

Работа с базой к GWT (тем более к SmartGWT) не относится. Погуглите OracleDataSource - там были примеры в т.ч. пул соединений.

Comment: попадал как то на апстик, но сейчас глаза открылись, какой классный сайт. Сколько времени у вас уходит на то что бы разобраться и написать такой пример?

Comment: "С нуля" даже предположить не могу. Подобную графику (без реальных данных) "копи-пастом из разных" около недели. 

Я занимаюсь Java с июня и уровень пока невысок.

Answer (score 0):

Кое-что попадалось по этой [теме](http://code-inside.net/smart-gwt-pervye-shagi/).

Answer (score 0):

Ну в качестве примера сайта на SmartGWT вот: http://www.musikcat.com
Там активно задействованы таблицы (ListGrid) и всплывающие окна (Window). В принципе у SmartGWT достаточно грамотно сделаны виджеты. Для ускорения загрузки SmartGWT javascript'ов (там около 5 мб!), используйте сервлетные фильтры. Например: https://code.google.com/p/webutilities/wiki/JSCSSMergeServlet